# Sync Vertical Scrolling in Notepad++ with Word Wrap On

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to read two large documents - same content in different languages, side by side in NP++ with sync vertical scrolling ON. This of course works, until I turn word wrap ON.

With word wrap, one document has larger lines than the other, meaning the documents go slowly out of sync as I scroll down.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you could open 2 instances of Notepad++ for each document, then by using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) you can create a script to replicate the same mouse wheel rotations of the first window to the second window each time a mouse wheel rotation is performed. If I were you, I'd ask for help over [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/). There is a high chance they might come up with a better solution than I did.

For Linux, as AutoHotkey is not working under it, you should use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

**Edit:**

I found the code for it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365826/how-to-simultaneously-scroll-two-windows/49780410#49780410):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#SingleInstance Force
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Process, Priority, , High
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

; Set your desired app names here. It is enough to use a part of the window's title
PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A := "Notepad++"
PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B := "Word"

GroupAdd, Scroll_Group, %PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A%
GroupAdd, Scroll_Group, %PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B%

SetWinDelay 0

#If (WinActive(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A) && WinExist(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B))
    || (WinActive(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B) && WinExist(PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A))

    WheelUp::
    WheelDown::
    PgUp::
    PgDn::
    Up::
    Down::  
        MouseGetPos, mX, mY
        Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}
        GroupActivate Scroll_Group  ; activate the next window of this group
        If (A_ThisHotKey = "WheelUp" || A_ThisHotKey = "WheelDown")
            MouseMove, 200, 200, 0  ; move the mouse over the currently active window 
        Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}   
        GroupActivate Scroll_Group
        MouseMove, mX, mY, 0
    return
```

To use this code install AutoHotkey, then save the code above to a file called `mouse_scroll_sync_over_2_windows.ahk`.

To demo this, I created 2 text files `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` filled with gibberish text so I can see the scrollbar moving, then I went into the .ahk file and modified these 2 parameters as follows:

```
PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_A := "test1.txt"
PART_OF_TITLE_OF_APP_B := "test2.txt"
```

After saving the .ahk file, I would run it. Now every time I'm scrolling in any of the 2 open text files in Notepad++, the other window's scroll will follow. Just make sure to first click with the mouse inside the text of the window before you scroll, otherwise the sync won't work.

The two above parameters use the partial title of a window. To get the title of a window you should use the **Window Spy** tool that comes with AutoHotkey.

This was tested with AutoHotkey Version 1.1.34.04 on Windows 10.

Comment: Does this work even when the two documents are not identical? What I mean is, with word wrap on, one file has larger lines (it's raw vs translation and the English translated file has larger number of words/characters compared to the non-English raw) so even if you scroll the same amount, the files would go out of sync.

What I'm looking for is a way to always sync line numbers between the two documents, even if that means they have to scroll by different heights.